# Express req.on('end', ...) not fired

Tags: node.js, express

My Express 'end' event is not emitted. Please shred some hints on how to fix it.

Express setup:

```
//Enable CORS
console.log("Enabled CORS and all pre-flight request");
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors()) // enable pre-flight request for ALL request
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }));   //James 11/7/2017
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));
```

Router setup:

```
//update
app.put('/:resourceType/id/:idPatient', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("update by Id [" + req.params.resourceType + "][" + req.params.idPatient + "][" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + "]");
        gModel.fhirUpdateById(req, res, next, false); // isDeleted = false
});
```

The `console.log` above can be seen every time,

```
// Handler
module.exports.fhirUpdateById = function (req, res, next, isDeleted) {

    var body = '';
    //Test 1: Direct call without req.on, then can't parse the body
    //updateById((req.params.resourceType, req.params.resourceId, res, next, req.body, isDeleted));

    //Test 2:
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log("fhirUpdateById Resource type: [" + req.params.resourceType + "]  Body: [" + body + "]");
        updateById((req.params.resourceType, req.params.resourceId, res, next, body, isDeleted));
    });
}
```

The `console.log` above is never shown. The `req.on('end', function () ...)` have never been fired up ;)

Questions:
1. How to fix the req.on('end'...) triggering?
2. Should I put the req.on('data') and req.on('end') on the app.use() since I would like to get the whole request on various PUT and POST?
3. If I don't use the req.on, will I get a partial body even though my body is less than 1MB?

Please let me know if you need more information.
Thanks.

========================================================

Resolved:

Please see Sandip's solution below.

In summary,

1. for http PUT, we should use either bodyParser.json or req.on('end', function), but not both. For http POST, we should use both;
2. the returned result from bodyParser.json is req.body which is a JSON object while req.on('end', function) is returning a string in my code;

Thanks ALL!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the issue. If you use body parser middleware, then none of the `data` or `end` event on request object is fired. I removed the body parser from your code, and the events started firing. Actually body parser does the job for you that you are trying to achieve through `data` event listener.

So, you either remove the body parser entirely

```
//Enable CORS
console.log("Enabled CORS and all pre-flight request");
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors()) // enable pre-flight request for ALL request

//update
app.put('/:resourceType/id/:idPatient', function (req, res, next) {
        console.log("update by Id [" + req.params.resourceType + "][" + req.params.idPatient + "][" + JSON.stringify(req.body) + "]");
        gModel.fhirUpdateById(req, res, next, false); // isDeleted = false
});
```

Or, you should use body parser and get the data from `req.body` directly

To understand how it works, you can see this [article](https://medium.com/@adamzerner/how-bodyparser-works-247897a93b90)

Comment: Hi Sandip. THANKS SO MUCH for the help. I will try it out soon and report back. This issue is so frustrated for me.

Comment: wc. Glad to help :)

Comment: Thanks Sandip. It is working perfectly now. Since I confused on bodyParser.json vs req.on('data', function), it has also affect the returned data type which is JSON object vs string. It is further messed my code.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - found out that requiring express.urlencoded on a route can also cause this same problem.  I ended up reorganizing my routes to separate out the affected route (into a separate file and route) from the routes that needed urlencoded.